# how to create multiple jsf datatable on click of command button

Tags: jsf

as per my requirement I have to create multiple blank datatable in ui on click of a button .
user can continuously add more tables on click .
as per my understanding I can add one datatable and can iterate over collection but how to add more.

```
<h:commandButton immediate="true"  styleClass="search_btn" value="Search" >
        <f:ajax listener="#{relationBean.searchRelation}" event="click"  />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton   immediate="true" value="Add Value">
<f:ajax listener="#{relationBean.addTable}" execute="relationId"  event="click" />
</h:commandButton>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

<h:dataTable rendered="#{relationBean.flagForDatatable}" value="#    {relationBean.elementRelationList}" var="element">
<h:column>
 <f:facet name="header"> Relation Type Name</f:facet>
 <h:outputText value="#{element.relationType}" />
 </h:column>
 <h:column>
 <f:facet name="header"> Value</f:facet>
 <h:inputText value="#{element.relationForm}" />
 </h:column>
 <h:column>
 <f:facet name="header">language</f:facet>
 <h:outputText value="#{element.languageCode.languageName}" />
 </h:column>
 <h:column>
 <f:facet name="header"> Delete</f:facet>
 <h:commandButton  value="Delete" />
 </h:column>

 </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `<ui:repeat>` to iterate over a collection and render the same JSF component structure multiple times.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.datatables}" var="datatable">
    <h:dataTable value="#{datatable.value}" var="item">
        ...
    </h:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

In the command button, just add a new item to the collection behind `#{bean.datatables}`.

Comment: thanks for providing logic. Its working. Now I have one more query that in my datatable last column is delete button. My requirement is to show only one delete button for the first time, not for each row.

Comment: Just press "Ask Question" to ask a question. Do not post questions as comments or answers on a completely different question. This way you won't be able to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

Belwo is the applied logic

```
<h:inputText id="relationId" class="relationship" value="#{relationBean.relationName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter relation">
<f:ajax></f:ajax>
</h:inputText> </div>

<h:commandButton  styleClass="search_btn" >
        <f:ajax listener="#{relationBean.searchRelation}" event="click"     render="addBtn"  execute="@all"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:messages id="msgGlobal" globalOnly="true"/>
    <h:commandButton id="addBtn" disabled="#{relationBean.showButton}" class="addvalue" value="Add Value">
<f:ajax listener="#{relationBean.addValue}" render="r"  event="click" />
</h:commandButton>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<h:panelGroup  id="r" >
<c:forEach id="repeat" items="#{relationBean.datatables}" var="">
<h:dataTable id="datatable"  value="#{relationBean.languageDTOList}" var="lang">
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"> Relation Type Name</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{relationBean.relationName}" />
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"> Value</f:facet>
    <h:inputText />
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">language</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{lang.languageName}" />
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"> Delete</f:facet>

    <h:commandButton  styleClass="remove_icon" value="Delete" >
    </h:commandButton>

</h:column>
```